# Calling sharepoint from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site that hold a very large list (more than 5000 items).
I was thinking of exposing a web service that eill return a list of guids. 
I have a class that returns said list and I am trying to instantiate the class from the web service. 
If I try to implment the class that returns the list of guid in an console application, everything works and I get the list of guids.
However, if i try to instantiate the class from a web service, when trying to open the site collection:

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSite))

I am getting an error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at XXXX could
>   not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL
>   should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need
>   to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Here is the code

```
    public void ProcessLargeList()
    {
        ContentIterator iterator = new ContentIterator();

        //Here it works in a console application, and fails once being called from with in a 
        //work service.

        using (var oSite = new SPSite(Site))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = strWeb.Length > 0
                ? oSite.OpenWeb(Web)
                : oSite.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList spDoc = oWeb.Lists[DocumentLibrary] as SPDocumentLibrary;

                if (Query != null && Query.Length > 0)
                {
                    SPQuery spquery = new SPQuery();
                    spquery.Query = Query;
                    spquery.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
                    Status = IterationStatus.Started;

                    //Runs through the content iterator and adds the items to the list of guids.

                    iterator.ProcessListItems(spDoc, spquery, ProcessListItem,
                        ProcessListItemError);
                }
                else
                {
                    iterator.ProcessListItems(spDoc, ProcessListItem,
                        ProcessListItemError);
                }
                Status = IterationStatus.Completed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Yossi

Comment: Does the web service runs on the same machine than the sharepoint server?

Comment: Yes it does run on the sever

Comment: Under which account are you running the web service? I experienced the same problem when account didn't have access to database.

Comment: Or maybe you have incorrectly configured alternate access mappings?

Comment: Which version of SP it is? if it's 2010, you have to ensure that your web services runs with the .Net V2.0 runtime. Not the V4.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the questions.

Comment: You also have to ensure that you application pools runs in 64 bits mode.

Comment: The account that I am using does have access to the database (I think. which database should i look into?) I will look into the alternate access mappings. The SP version is 2010 and the web service runs under .net v2.0

Comment: SP is running under server 2008 r2, 64 bit. How do i find under which processor does the application pool runs.

Comment: It does not enable 32-bit application, so i suppose it runs under 32 bit

Comment: Apologies, i meant it runs under 64 bit